# How to get the SharePoint Migration Assessment Tool to scan a particular application available in server

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, migration, sharepointmigrationtool

I am doing a site migration from 2013 on-premise to SharePoint Online. I downloaded the SMAT tool to find issues for migration, but that tool is not scanning the application I needed; its taking some other applications. How can I scan a particular site with the SMAT tool?

Comment: So did you test `SharePoint Migration Tool` as described in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

## Microsoft tool

My advice is to use `SharePoint Migration Tool` (SPMT) : this free software includes an [assessment tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/spmt-scan). It's a more modern tool from Microsoft than the "old" `SharePoint Migration Assessment Tool` (SMAT).

[image: SPMT]

## Third-party tool

You can also download and try a demonstration version of [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/microsoft-migration). You can select a subset of sites. Pricing is very competitive regarding the features offered.